# C# Difference between cast types

Tags: c#, casting

What is the difference between the two types of casts available in c#?

Specifically, what is the difference between. 
 `(int)7.6` and `7.6 as int` and similar casts?

Comment: `7.6 as int` won't compile because the `as` operator returns `null` if the cast it not possible. Since `null` cannot be assigned to an `int`, the code will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

as will return null if it can't convert to the given type. Casting will throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

The `as` operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, `as` returns null.

if you use an implicit cast and the cast is not possible you will get an exception.